# UIPageViewController inside a UIStackView or UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I was trying to create an onboarding UI using UIKit and Storyboard. I had a requirement where some parts needed to be static / sticky and some parts had to scroll horizontally as the user swiped on the onboarding.

This should give you a better idea:

[image: Onboarding swift UIPageViewController in UIStackView UIScrollView UITableView Autolayout]

To achieve the above, I used the following view hierarchy set up in storyboard

UIViewController

- Skip Button
- Container View containing a UIPageViewController to swipe horizontally

  - UIViewController

    - UIScrollView (This is another scroll view, not the page view controller's)

      - UIStackView

        - UIImage (big red cross)
        - UILabel
        - UILabel
- UIStackView
- Page Indicator
- Subscribe button
- Login button

While this works fine in a normal set up, I have the need to support dynamic / large text which the user can update from settings / control panel.

The issue I have now is that the content grows within the scrollview inside the UIPageViewController as shown

[image: UIStackView UIScrollView UIPageController Swift Onboarding]

The white box above is not part of the UI but just me trying to show that the vertical scrolling is restricted to that area.

I understand that because of my set up, this is the correct behavior.

My question / objective:
What would be a better layout structure so that the whole view grows when larger text fonts are activated such that the view scrolls as a whole rather than the scrolling being restricted to that small portion of the screen which would be mean the page indicator and bottom buttons going below the screen for larger text sizes.

Please bear in mind that only the image, title and description should be horizontally scrollable.

I tried to bring the scrollview and stackview out of the PageViewController to set up something like this:

UIViewController

- UIScrollView

  - UIStackView

    - Skip Button
    - Container View containing a UIPageViewController to swipe horizontally

      - UIViewController

        - UIStackView

          - UIImage (big red cross)
          - UILabel
          - UILabel
    - UIStackView

      - Page Indicator
      - Subscribe button
      - Login button

However, since I'm using autolayout, I get an error in the storyboard that the page view controller's height couldn't be determined.

What would be the right way to set this up in storyboard or programatically if not possible via storyboard ?

I'm open to switching to tableview or collectionview if that makes life easier.

Comment: This seems like more of a **Design** question than a code / layout management question. For example - do you **really** want to allow your "Onboarding 1" label font to grow to that size? That is, will it be "user friendly" to see the word broken like that? Are you embedding the vertical scrollview because your "description" will potentially be many lines? Would it make more sense to vertically scroll only the **text**?

Comment: @DonMag The title and description could potentially be multiple lines yes, however, we try to keep it to 1-2 lines max so as to avoid the need to scroll. The main reason for the scrollview is to allow the text size to grow when the user selects a bigger text size from settings / control center. If the text size is set to 150 - 300%, the text requires to be scrolled. Rather than just scrolling the text, I would prefer the whole view to be scrollable.

Comment: Is this close to your goal? https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7H0d.png ... page view controller frame has constant height, regardless of vertical-scrolling text inside it?

Comment: @DonMag - Thanks for the illustration, it's almost what I want. I would like to remove the scroll view inside the PageVC and so the PageVC can grow based on the content. The only scrollview is the one outside which you marked in yellow so that the whole view scrolls in the safe area. When the content in the PageVC grows, the buttons etc would get pushed further down in the yellow scrollview from your illustration. Hope that makes sense ?

Comment: So, you want the PageVC **height** to change based on the **page** content... What should happen to the buttons as the user swipes between pages? That brings us back to **design** question... Take a look at this image - I think you'll see what I mean (really, really big image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVfvB.jpg

Comment: @DonMag - thanks, this is amazing. This is pretty much what I wanted. As the text height grows, the page indicator and buttons push further down. As the user swipes between the pages, the skip button, the page indicator and the 2 bottom buttons should just remain on the page and not scroll along with the image and text. I agree about your question - is this good design ? Well, we do try to keep the text between 1 and 2 lines, so all the UI elements would be seen. However, we need this support in the event of increased accessibility font size which pushes the buttons down and thats fine.

Comment: A bit confusing... your previous comment said *"I would like to remove the scroll view inside the PageVC ... only scrollview is the one outside which you marked in yellow so that the whole view scrolls in the safe area."* ... but now you're saying you want the text to scroll but ***not*** the buttons?

Comment: sorry @DonMag for the confusion. To clarify, the horizontal scrolling / paging should only happen for the image and text. The vertical scrolling as the content grows should apply to everything including the buttons. Hope that clarifies / makes sense ?

Comment: OK - so, in that really big image... Do you want the **top** layout or the **bottom** layout? If you want the **top**, how do you envision handling the buttons (and the page control) moving up and down as you swipe from page to page? Or.... ***also*** slide the page control and buttons left/right - so you have one set on each "page"?

Comment: @DonMag - I want the top layout and the closest sentence in your image to what I want is the one proposed in the middle section "Page View Controller changes height to match the tallest Page Height. Buttons and page indicator should move up and down as the user swipes between pages and remain constant as the user swipes horizontally." This means the buttons and page control is just one and is not part of each "page". Hope this answers the question.

Comment: OK - you *probably* don't want to use a `UIPageVIewController` ... take a look at this: https://youtu.be/OPKYXKwPEC0 ... the black frame is the device frame ... yellow dashed outline is the vertical "all elements" scroll view ... white dashed outline is the horizontal "page" scroll view ... pages are outlined in blue ... as would probably be obvious, when running on a device we won't see what's outside of the scroll view frames. If that matches your goal, I'll post code and explanation as an answer.

Comment: This is amazing and exactly what I want @DonMag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comment discussion, I *think* I understand your ultimate goal.

You're creating an "Onboarding" UI, so I'll make a few assumptions...

- likely not **dozens** of "pages"
- likely fairly "static" pages (no or very little user interaction on each "page")

Therefore, we shouldn't have to worry about memory issues if the "pages" are not dynamically allocated.

A `UIPageViewController` is a nice component -- but, it does a LOT "behind-the-scenes." In particular, it sets the "page frames" to match its frame. In your case, you want ***its*** frame to grow in height to match the ***pages*** height.

That probably could be done, but it will be much easier to NOT use a page view controller.

Instead, let's use a standard `UIScrollView`.

---

First, if we embed a `UILabel` in a `UIView`, and constrain the Height of the **view** equal to the Height of the **label** (assuming we have 8-point constraints from the table to the view):

```
someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someLabel.heightAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
```

the Yellow **view** will grow in height as the **label** grows:

[image]

We can do the same thing with a `UIScrollView` (red-dashed outline is the scroll view frame):

[image]

The scroll view frame Height grows with the label height, and we can still scroll horizontally but not vertically.

---

So, let's start by putting the "pages" into a horizontal stack view:

[image]

and then embed that stack view in a scroll view.

If we constrain each page Width to the Width of the scroll view, and set a Height constraint on the scroll view, we'll get this (thick black dashed outline is the scroll view frame):

[image]

So far, nothing special.

However, if the **page** heights change - such as using `.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory - true` on the labels - without doing anything else - we get this:

[image]

[image]

which results in vertical as well as horizontal scrolling -- as expected.

For the target layout, though, we want the **scroll view's Height** to grow to match the new **page Height**.

Let's constrain the scroll view's Height to the stack view's Height:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // "normal" Top/Leading/Trailing constraints
        pageScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        pageScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        pageScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        
        // instead of setting a Height related to the view, or a constant value
        //  we'll constrain the Height to the *stack view's* height
        pageScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageStackView.heightAnchor),
    ])
```

Now, as our "pages" grow in height, the scroll view frame will also grow:

[image]

[image]

Once we embed our `pageScrollView` in an "outer" scroll view, and constrain it relative to the other "outer" UI elements, we'll reach the target layout.

Solid black outline is the "iPhone" frame; yellow long-dash outline is the "outer" scroll view frame; white dash outline is the "page" scroll view frame:

[image]

As the "page" height grows...

[image]

we'll be able to scroll the entire "outer view" vertically...

[image]

and continue to scroll the "pages" horizontally.

[image]

[image]

The end result - (scaled way down so it will post here):

[image]

And, finally, some sample code. Everything is done via code, so no complicated Storyboard designing or `@IBOutlet` / `@IBAction` connections needed:

---

**Simple struct for the "page" data:**

```
struct PageData {
    var title: String = ""
    var desc: String = ""
    
    // maybe different images on each page?
    var imgName: String = ""
}
```

---

**Sample "page" view controller** - which we'll add as children and grab the views. ImageView, Title and Description labels:

```
class SamplePageVC: UIViewController {
    
    let titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    let descLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    let imgView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        guard let customFont1 = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 32.0),
              let customFont2 = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 16.0)
        else {
            fatalError("Could not load font!")
        }
        
        titleLabel.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: customFont1)
        descLabel.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: customFont2)
        
        [titleLabel, descLabel].forEach { v in
            v.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.textColor = .white
            v.numberOfLines = 0
            v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        }
        
        // might want to set a MAX Content Size Category?
        //view.maximumContentSizeCategory = .accessibilityExtraLarge
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing = 6
        
        [imgView, titleLabel, descLabel].forEach { v in
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let bc: NSLayoutConstraint = stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0)
        bc.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            bc,
            
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            
            titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            descLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
    }
    
}
```

---

**Sample "onboarding" view controller** - uses everything discussed above:

```
class OnboardingVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let skipBtn: UIButton = UIButton()
    let subscribeBtn: UIButton = UIButton()
    let loginBtn: UIButton = UIButton()
    
    let pgCtrl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
    
    let outerScrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let outerContentView: UIView = UIView()
    
    let pageScrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    let pageStackView: UIStackView = UIStackView()
    
    var pageData: [PageData] = [
        PageData(title: "First Page", desc: "Some description about it.", imgName: "pgXC"),
        PageData(title: "Short", desc: "This page has somewhat longer description text.", imgName: ""),
        PageData(title: "A Longer Title", desc: "This page will have even more text in the description label. That will help demonstrate the height matching and resulting layout / scrolling changes.", imgName: ""),
        PageData(title: "Final", desc: "This is the last page.", imgName: ""),
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .init(red: 1.0, green: 0.25, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
        
        guard let skipFont = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 17.0),
              let btnFont = UIFont(name: "Verdana-Bold", size: 16.0)
        else {
            fatalError("Could not load font!")
        }

        skipBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: skipFont)
        subscribeBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: btnFont)
        loginBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: btnFont)

        for (btn, str) in zip([skipBtn, subscribeBtn, loginBtn], ["Skip", "Subscribe", "Login"]) {
            btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
            btn.setTitle(str, for: [])
            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        }
        
        skipBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        skipBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        skipBtn.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        
        subscribeBtn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        subscribeBtn.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .highlighted)
        subscribeBtn.backgroundColor = .white
        
        loginBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        loginBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        loginBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        loginBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        let btnStack: UIStackView = UIStackView()
        btnStack.axis = .vertical
        btnStack.spacing = 12
        
        // let's add top and bottom padding for the buttons
        //  we're not using UIButtonConfiguration so we ignore the deprecation warnings
        [subscribeBtn, loginBtn].forEach { v in
            var edges = v.contentEdgeInsets
            edges.top = 12.0
            edges.bottom = 12.0
            v.contentEdgeInsets = edges
        }
        
        // add Page Control and bottom buttons to vertical stack view
        //  set Hugging and Compression priorities to .required so they
        //  won't stretch or collapse vertically
        [pgCtrl, subscribeBtn, loginBtn].forEach { v in
            btnStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        }
        
        // add "pages" stack view to "page" scroll view
        pageStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pageScrollView.addSubview(pageStackView)
        
        // add elements to outerContentView
        [skipBtn, pageScrollView, btnStack].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            outerContentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // add outerContentView to outerScrollView
        outerContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        outerScrollView.addSubview(outerContentView)
        
        // add outerScrollView to (self) view
        outerScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(outerScrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        var cg = pageScrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        var fg = pageScrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of pageStackView to pageScrollView.contentLayoutGuide
            pageStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            pageStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            pageStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            pageStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain skip button Top/Trailing
            skipBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            skipBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // constrain pageScrollView
            //  Top 8-points below skip button Bottom
            //  Leading/Trailing to outerContentView (so, full width)
            pageScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: skipBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            pageScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            pageScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain pageScrollView HEIGHT to pageStackView HEIGHT
            //  now, the scroll view Height will match the "pages" height
            pageScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageStackView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain btnStack
            //  Top >= pageScrollView Bottom plus a little "padding space"
            //  Leading/Trailing to outerContentView plus a little "padding space" on the sides
            //  Bottom to outerContentView plus a little "padding space"
            btnStack.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: pageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            btnStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            btnStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerContentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
        ])
        
        cg = outerScrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        fg = outerScrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        // we want outerContentView to be the same Height as outerScrollView
        //  but less-than-required Priority so it can grow based on its subviews
        let hc: NSLayoutConstraint = outerContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        hc.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of outerContentView to outerScrollView.contentLayoutGuide
            outerContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // outerContentView Width to outerScrollView.frameLayoutGuide Width
            //  so we will never get horizontal scrolling
            outerContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            hc,
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of outerScrollView to (self) view
            outerScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        // add page view VCs for each data item
        //  we could do this with a "SamplePageView" UIView subclass
        //  but this shows how to use UIViewController if that's how the "pages" are setup
        
        for (idx, d) in pageData.enumerated() {
            
            let vc = SamplePageVC()
            
            addChild(vc)
            
            // add its view to pageStackView
            pageStackView.addArrangedSubview(vc.view)
            
            vc.didMove(toParent: self)
            
            vc.titleLabel.text = d.title
            vc.descLabel.text = d.desc
            
            if !d.imgName.isEmpty, let img = UIImage(named: d.imgName) {
                vc.imgView.image = img
            } else if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(idx).circle.fill") {
                vc.imgView.image = img
                vc.imgView.tintColor = .orange
            }
            
            // each page view Width is equal to pageScrollView.frameLayoutGuide width
            vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            
        }
        
        // we *probably* do not want to see scroll indicators
        outerScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        outerScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        // enable paging for the "pages"
        pageScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        // we will implement scrollViewDidScroll() so we can update the page control
        //  when the user drags the pages left/right
        pageScrollView.delegate = self
        
        pgCtrl.numberOfPages = pageData.count
        pgCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changePage(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
    }
    
    @objc func changePage(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        let x: CGFloat = pageScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(sender.currentPage)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.pageScrollView.contentOffset.x = x
        })
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == pageScrollView {
            let pg: Int = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.width * 0.5) / scrollView.frame.width))
            pgCtrl.currentPage = pg
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

**Sample *Dev Mode* "onboarding" view controller** - subclass of `OnboardingVC` the colorizes and outlines the UI elements. It will produce the screen-caps shown above (when run on an iPad) to make it easier to see what's going on:

```
// MARK: subclass of OnboardingVC
//  for use during development
//  colorizes and outlines view elements
//  centers a "simulated" device frame so we can see "outside the frame"

class DevOnboardingVC: OnboardingVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // we need to re-build the outerScrollView constraints
        outerScrollView.removeFromSuperview()
        view.addSubview(outerScrollView)
        
        // we'll make the "device frame"
        //  90% of the view height, or
        //  640-points, whichever is smaller
        let targetHeightC: NSLayoutConstraint = outerScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9)
        targetHeightC.priority = .required - 1
        let maxHeightC: NSLayoutConstraint = outerScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 640.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            outerScrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            outerScrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            outerScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            maxHeightC, targetHeightC,
            
        ])
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)
        
        outerContentView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 1.0, green: 0.25, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
        
        outerScrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        pageScrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        
        pageStackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            v.backgroundColor = .init(red: 1.0, green: 0.25, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
            v.layer.borderWidth = 2
        }
        self.children.forEach { vc in
            if let vc = vc as? SamplePageVC {
                vc.titleLabel.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
                vc.descLabel.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
            }
        }
        
        let dashV1 = DashedBorderView()
        dashV1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(dashV1)
        
        let dashV2 = DashedBorderView()
        dashV2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(dashV2)
        
        let dashV3 = DashedBorderView()
        dashV3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(dashV3)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dashV1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            dashV2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            dashV3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dashV3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        dashV1.color = .black
        dashV1.lineWidth = 16
        dashV1.position = .outside
        dashV1.dashPattern = []
        
        dashV2.color = .systemYellow
        dashV2.lineWidth = 3
        dashV2.dashPattern = [60, 8]
        
        dashV3.color = .white
        dashV3.lineWidth = 2
        
    }
    
}
```

---

**Dashed Border View** - used by the "Dev Mode" class:

```
class DashedBorderView: UIImageView {

    enum BorderPosition {
        case inside, middle, outside
    }
    
    public var position: BorderPosition = .middle { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var dashPattern: [NSNumber] = [16, 16] { didSet { dashedLineLayer.lineDashPattern = dashPattern } }
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet { dashedLineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth } }
    public var color: UIColor = .red { didSet { dashedLineLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor } }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAShapeLayer.self }
    var dashedLineLayer: CAShapeLayer { layer as! CAShapeLayer }
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // this view will usually be overlaid on top of an interactive view
        //  so disable by default
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        dashedLineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        dashedLineLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        dashedLineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        dashedLineLayer.lineDashPattern = dashPattern
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        switch position {
        case .inside:
            dashedLineLayer.path = CGPath(rect: bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth * 0.5, dy: lineWidth * 0.5), transform: nil)
        case .outside:
            dashedLineLayer.path = CGPath(rect: bounds.insetBy(dx: -lineWidth * 0.5, dy: -lineWidth * 0.5), transform: nil)
        case .middle:
            dashedLineLayer.path = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

**Important Notes**

- This is ***Example Code Only!!!*** It is not intended to be, nor should be considered, "Production Ready"
- Design is for iPhone Portrait orientation... it will still *work* on an iPad, or on a phone rotated to Landscape, but I promise it won't look good :)

I also posted a project with all the above code here: https://github.com/DonMag/PageViewApproach

---

**Edit** - *a little more explanation...*

Big benefits of using a `UIPageViewController` or `UICollectionView` (whether using flow, custom or compositional layout) is **memory management** ... you could have 100s of "pages" and not have to worry.

With this Layout goal, though, the *dynamic height* is always going to be the issue... because both of those classes are **also** designed to "layout their pages / cells" based on the frame we set for the PageViewController or CollectionView.

Consider 5 "pages" that look like this:

[image]

In a page view controller or a collection view, we can't set the frame height (yellow rect) because we don't know the "max height needed" ***until Page 4 is instantiated***.

We *could* calculate the max height on load, for example:

```
func getMaxHeight() -> CGFloat {
    
    var maxHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    for i in 0..<numPages {
        let v = MyPageView()
        v.fillLabels(forPage: i)
        let sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        maxHeight = max(maxHeight, sz.height)
    }
    return maxHeight
    
}
```

Or, if we have "cached" the page views in memory:

```
func getMaxHeight() -> CGFloat {
    
    var maxHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    pageViews.forEach { v in
        let sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        maxHeight = max(maxHeight, sz.height)
    }
    return maxHeight
    
}
```

And because you're using Dynamic Type, we'd **also** need to call that on `UITraitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory` change and update the frame height.

Personally, I would go with the scrollview approach, and simply let auto-layout handle it for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot DonMag, amazing answer and explanation - exactly what I was trying to achieve. Really appreciate the time and effort you put into this. Your assumptions are right that we won't have more than 5-6 pages. As a final question, do you think something similar could also be achieved with a UICollectionView Compositional layout ? Thanks once again, really appreciate this.

Comment: @ShawnFrank - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer for additional explanation.

Comment: Perfect, amazing answer, covers all basis and I've learn a ton from you - Thanks DonMag !